# How to get the value of an MSBuild variable

Tags: msbuild

How can I get the value of MSBuild variable (ex. `$(MSBuildToolsPath)`, `$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)`, `$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)`, etc.).

I need to get the value on the C# side, but I can access msbuild.exe if it's not available from the C# code.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want - are you trying to programatically load/build an msbuild project? What did you try so far? There are enough examples out there on how to build programmatically using C# and get/set project properties.

Comment: @stijn yes, I execute the msbuild target from c# side by BuildManager. For this I need to get all targets from the project file. But msbuild supports the importing of projects that can use msbuild variables. So I need to have ability to get the value of the variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuildManager and the likes are for building, only; Microsoft decided to split up the [MSBuild API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt443866.aspx) in different namespaces according to functionality. Once you know that it's not too hard figuring out what you need: you just need to evaluate properties, so the [Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx) class from the Evaluation namespace seems like the proper choice. It has a Properties member exposing all properties:

```
var project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project( @"my.vcxproj" );
foreach( var property in p.Properties )
{
  System.Console.WriteLine( "{0} = {1}",
    property.Name, property.EvaluatedValue );
}
```