# Access MSBuild Parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild

To avoid having to save an API ClientId in the code (and in a public code repo on Github), I want to pass it as a parameter when building the project using MSBuild (with Jenkins and ClickOnce).

The [parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) I set in the Jenkins config:
`/p:ApiClientId="abcde"`

However, I wasn't able to find a way to access the parameter from within my C#-code. What I tried:

- [Assign parameter value taken from a property in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919515/assign-parameter-value-taken-from-a-property-in-msbuild)
- [How to get value of MsBuild variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669419/how-to-get-value-of-msbuild-variable)

Not sure if I am missing something...

Comment: Why don't you put that client id in the config file and read it?

Comment: What config file? The app is deployed to 100eds of users using ClickOnce and Jenkins). We don't have a config file that we manually distribute, and we also would not want to have one that we package with the app (because it would need to be checked into a code repo). The only solution I can imagine is to add it from the build server (because that's not OpenSource). Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with fetching the client id (API secret) from my server. That way, I can also easily change it, without having to update the clients.